# R: Error with the 'rbind' function while trying to add data frames converted from csv files

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, for-loop, rbind

**Data:** 
The drive folder containing the data can be downloaded here: [specdata](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EhirUW-Xzr64Ynb9fir5p0RUptDzOv02). The folder contains 332 comma-separated-value (CSV) files containing pollution monitoring data for fine particulate matter (PM) air pollution at 332 locations in the United States. Each file contains data from a single monitor and the ID number for each monitor is contained in the file name. For example, data for monitor 200 is contained in the file “200.csv”. Each file contains three variables. Date: the date of the observation in (year-month-day) format, sulfate: the level of sulfate PM in the air on that date (measured in micrograms per cubic meter), and nitrate: the level of nitrate PM in the air on that date (measured in micrograms per cubic meter)

**Objective**
Write a function named ‘pollutantmean’ that calculates the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function ‘pollutantmean’ takes three arguments: ‘directory’, ‘pollutant’, and ‘id’. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, ‘pollutantmean’ reads that monitors’ particulate matter data from the directory specified in the ‘directory’ argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, ignoring any missing values coded as NA.

**Script:**

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant, id) {
  originaldir = getwd()
  setwd(paste(getwd(),"/",directory,sep = "")) ##assuming the needed folder (i.e specdata in this case) is present in originaldir
  samples <- dir()
  master.data.frame <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=2,ncol=4)) ##creating an empty data frame with number of columns equal to the csv files and random number of rows.
  if (pollutant == "Sulphate") {
    pollutant.index = 2   ## assigning column number for sulphate
  } else {
    pollutant.index = 3   ## assigning column number for nitrate
  }
  for (i in id) {
    files <- as.data.frame(read.csv(samples[i]))
    master.data.frame <- rbind(master.data.frame,files)
  }

  means <- colMeans(master.data.frame[pollutant.index],na.rm = TRUE)
  setwd(originaldir)
  print(means)
}
```

**Calling the function:**

```
pollutantmean("specdata","sulphate",1:10)
```

**Error Message**

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names 
5. stop("names do not match previous names") 
4. match.names(clabs, names(xi)) 
3. rbind(deparse.level, ...) 
2. rbind(master.data.frame, files) 
1. pollutantmean("specdata", "sulphate", 1:10)
```

The goal is to create a master data frame with all readings from all the csv files and then filter it for columns and without NA values by using the colMeans function. This is where the code is coming apart.

Please let me know how to resolve the error.

Comment: You may try to use `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `rbind`

Comment: Extending iago's point: iteratively building a frame with repeated `rbind` works fine for a few, but each time it is called, the frame is copied *completely* from the old into the new. As the frame gets larger, this will take more time for each `rbind`. Much better to either (1) pre-allocate a `list`, assigning the interim frame to increasing indices within the list in the `for` loop, then binding them *once* with `do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)` (or `bind_rows` ...); or (2) using `lapply` and then binding them all at once (`do.call` or `bind_rows`).

Comment: @iago - using bind_rows resulted in the similar errors. The initiation of the data frame turned out to be the major error. Thank You for your input regardless :)

Comment: @r2evans - tried it by preallocating a list too! Works great! Thank You for this approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your initial data frame does not have the same column names, as those read from your files. You could construct it with the correct names but it is much easier to let it be `NULL` and initialize like this:

```
master.data.frame <- NULL
```

Of course r2evans is absolutely right that repeated rbinding is not at all efficient. But it may be good enough – you decide for your application.

And some unsolicited remarks:

I would avoid to use `setwd` and instead construct the correct path to the data using `file.path` and use that in `read.csv`.

I would also try to avoid addressing the columns of a data.frame by numeric index and use the column names, instead.

Finally – `read.csv` already returns a data.frame – no need to cast it.

Here's a slightly cleand up version:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id) {
    master.data.frame <- NULL
    allfiles <- list.files(directory)
    for (i in id) {
        thisfile <- read.csv(file.path(directory, allfiles[i]))
        master.data.frame <- rbind(master.data.frame,thisfile)
    }

    means <- colMeans(master.data.frame[pollutant],na.rm = TRUE)
    print(means)
}
```

Comment: Letting master.data.frame be NULL worked as a treat! Works perfectly fine now.
Thanks a ton @Phil!